# Is it possible to catch all exceptions using aspectj?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I would like to make sure an advice is executed every time an exception is thrown by a method that is annotated with a specific annotation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are after-throwing advice. [See here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-advice.html)